# When using an uploadSpec with Artifactory, can I get Artifactory to generate a default POM?

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, maven-3, artifactory

I am using an uploadSpec and rtUpload in Jenkins DSL pipeline to upload a zip file to Artifactory:

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "pattern": "dist/(*)-(*)-(*).zip",
      "target": "internal/com/a/b/c/{1}/{2}-{3}/{1}-{2}-{3}.zip"
    }
  ]
}
```

If I instead deploy using the UI, I can ask it to generate a default POM for me.  What's the easiest way to get a POM up there so Maven can find my uploads using targets such as:

```
mvn versions:display-dependency-updates
```

At the moment, i'm running that command and it's failing with a 404 on maven-metadata.xml does not exist yet, and I think this is because artifactory has not spotted any poms in the repo?  Even though my zip file is uploaded using a maven layout.

Hope this makes sense

Comment: **Update**  I couldn't find a way of doing this so I am using the uploadSpec to upload a pom file (alongside the zip), and i'm having to create this pom manually myself.  This seems to sort out mvn versions

Comment: pls attach pom.xml